# UIView mysteriously expand by 1 pix when added to as subview

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I created a custom "component" made up of UIView and it gets added as subview on any visible view. What I found strange is that when it get added to a view the second time, the width got increased by 1 pix. This caused a problem when it expanded the background image and causes the image to blur out.

Any ideas why a view will get expanded (or shrink) when added to another view?

Comment: Before adding the component second time, try printing the components frame values and confirm whether values are as per expected or increased by 1 pixel.

Comment: Also be sure the parent view does not get resized between the moment you add your view on it and the moment you get the measure.

Comment: Yup, the reason why I know it's expanded by 1pix is by printing out the size values. I will follow VDesmedT suggestion -- sounds like a possible cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be related to the location of the view.
Perhaps one of these stories will shed more light on the issue:

[Fixing Blurry Subviews](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiview-blurred-blurry-view/)

[Why does a PNG image sometimes get blurry depending on its position in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170167/why-does-a-png-image-sometimes-get-blurry-depending-on-its-position-in-a-view)